# Having VirtueMart to Update a Specific Table on Success

Tags: php, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I was wondering where I should add my own table update codes in VirtueMart, when a successful transaction occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy this file:

```
/components/com_virtuemart/views/cart/tmpl/order_done.php
```

Put your code and create an override to:

```
/templates/*template_name/html/com_virtuemart/cart/order_done.php
```

You could also create a [plugin](http://dev.virtuemart.net/projects/virtuemart/wiki/Plugin_system) but `plgVmOnConfirmedOrderStorePaymentData()` event is only for payment plugins.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. But there are some parts I don't understand. In order_done.php, all I can see is: "echo $this->html" and I don't know where it's shown. I have no idea about how to override your second line and I can't see any html/ in joomla's template folder. Could you explain more? tnx

Comment: Oh, you know what? I just added my UPDATE query at the top of echo $this->html, and it worked. But, the thing is it runs whether it's a success or a cancel. Do you know how to put a condition on this, to make sure if it's a successfully paid transaction?

Comment: As for the first question, if html folder doesn't exist you have to create it. As for successfull payment you have to put the code to the payment plugin. That would be hard as you have to add it to each payment method or to make the addition in admin side script once you manually do the order update.

Comment: I got it. Actually, there is one payment method that contains function plgVmConfirmedOrder(). I'm trying to put the code in there...

Answer (score 1):

In old VM it would be in ps_checkout.php. Not sure about the newer version.